# UIKit code is not called after OpenGL ES is loaded

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, opengl-es

I have followed a tutorial on http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/make-a-neon-vector-shooter-for-ios-first-steps--gamedev-14316 (I'm at part 3 right now) to learn basic OpenGL ES for iOS.

I wanted to make a play/restart menu so I started to work with the UIViewController and GLView. Now I can log whenever I'm game over from the UIViewController, I can log my gamestate and every frame, but every time I use a UIKit call it gets ignored in viewDidLoad. I tried something small like changing a HUD view's color, this works but when I change the HUB's color at game over, it does nothing.

I tried to log right before and right after I change the color and it does log

Here is my code that I call when I'm game over:

```
void    PlayerStatus::returnToMenu() {
     NSLog(@"returned to menu");
     newIntProg++;
     newIntProg++;
     ViewController *vCont = [ViewController alloc];
     [vCont setGameProgVal:newIntProg];
     //return;
}
```

And here is the call from viewController:

```
- (void) setGameProgVal:(int)newProg {
     [gvar setNewValFrom:newProg];
     //NSLog(@"%i", newProg);
     if (newProg == 2) {
         NSLog(@"%i", newProg);
         NSLog(@"it works...");
         [HUDView setAlpha:1.0];
         NSLog(@"this works to");
         [HUDView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
         NSLog(@"this allso works");
   }
```

All NSLog calls are performed, but the HUD color doesn't change.

Comment: I'm unclear what you mean by your UIKit calls being ignored in `viewDidLoad`. Why would that method have a historic record of preceding calls? Also, you want `[[ViewController alloc] init]` or `[ViewController new]`, not just `[ViewController alloc]`. In Objective-C constructors are called by convention rather than as part of the language so `alloc` alone creates space but doesn't actually do construction. It made more sense before `allocWithZone:` was deprecated but is still defensible on small runtime grounds, I think. `new` is defined on `NSObject` to call `alloc` and `init`.

Comment: my code is getting called by vewDidLoad, but when i call a UIKit method from within my OpenGL ES code thats in my ViewController, i get the NSLog's i added but not the actual UIKit changes
allo, i tried the [[ViewController Alloc] Init]; and [ViewControler New]; and they didn't change anything